# simple html dom get image from script jwplayer code

Tags: javascript, php, simple-html-dom

```
<?php
 include('simple_html_dom.php');
 $htmls = file_get_html('src.html');

 preg_match( "/file:'(.+?)'/", $html, $matches );
 echo $matches[1];
    ?>
```

i am using simple_html_dom.php to get IMAGE from script, but it isn't working .
in other code it's working .

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
      var timer = 10;
      var countdown;

      var jwplplayerSetup = jwplayer('jw').setup({
        'modes': [
            {type: 'flash', src: 'http://www.myvideo.ge/flv_player/j/playerNew.swf'}
        ],

         'file': 'http://80.241.248.25/flv/216/2153964.mp4',
        'image': 'http://thumbs2.myvideo.ge/screens/216/2153964.jpg',
        'backcolor': '111111',
        'frontcolor': 'cccccc',
        'lightcolor': 'D10000',
        'autostart': 'true',
        'margin':0,


            }
        },
        });
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because `E_DOESNT_WORK` is not a known PHP error state.

Comment: Space is missing after `file':` in your pattern. Read help center, before you ask any other question again. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file attribute has single quotes (') around it, and there is a space after the colon. You need to account for these in your regular expression. The following line worked for me:

preg_match( "/'file': '(.+?)'/", $html, $matches );